# Generic метод

Tags: android, java

Есть метод, который устанавливает адаптер и записывает в него набор данных. Есть 4 типа данных, расширяющих СуперКласс.
Для того, чтобы инициализировать адаптер, я использую 4 метода (по 1 для каждого набора данных):

```
setTypeDogAsAdapter();
setTypeCatAsAdapter();
```

... и т.д.

```
setTypeDogAsAdapter(){
  final ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        petAdapter = new PetListAdapter(this, groups);
        petAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
        for (Dog dog: petService.getPetItemListHolder().getItems()) {
                dogs .add(dog);
            } 
 ...

}
```

И так **4** раза.

Хочется сделать что-то вроде

```
setPetsAdapter(Dog);
setPetsAdapter(Cat);
```

и т.д.

```
final ArrayList<<? extends Pet>> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        petAdapter = new PetListAdapter(this, groups);
        petAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
        for (... ... : petService.getPetItemListHolder().getItems()) {
               ... .add(...);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша задача решается передачей в generic метод класса, которым метод должен быть параметризован:

```
public <T> void setPetsAdapter(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> pets = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T pet : petService.getPetItemListHolder().getItems()) {
        pets.add(pet);
    }
    ...
}

setPetsAdapter(Dog.class);
setPetsAdapter(Cat.class);
```

Однако, тут возникает проблема: метод `petService.getPetItemListHolder()` возвращает... что? `List<Pet>`? В таком случае код не скомпилируется, так как есть риск кастануть `Cat` к `Dog` (если, например, коллекция, возвращаемая `petService.getPetItemListHolder()` содержит экземпляры обоих классов, а мы вызвали метод `setPetsAdapter` с параметром `Dog`). Так что метод `petService.getPetItemListHolder()` также придётся параметризовать, чтобы он гарантированно возвращал коллекцию объектов, совместимых с параметром метода `setPetsAdapter` (я немного упростил пример для наглядности):

```
public <T> List<T> getPetItemList(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}

public <T> void setPetsAdapter(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> pets = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T pet : getPetItemList(clazz)) {
        pets.add(pet);
    }
    ...
}

setPetsAdapter(Dog.class);
setPetsAdapter(Cat.class);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял, где неправильно было и что почитать.